# Execute Predefined scenes in iOS 9

Tags: homekit, ios-homekit

Hi I have updated my Xcode and iOS . In the iOS 9 they have made some changes in HomeKit. In that they have by default added some predefined scenes. like `HMActionSetTypeSleep`,`HMActionSetTypeWakeUp` ... When I click on that scene in HMCatalog app it throws error that no actions in the actions. Could any one please tell me how to execute the `HMActionSetTypeWakeUp` type built in scenes.Thank you for your valuable time. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Scenes' by itself are HMAction aggregators, i.e. HMActionSets. You need to add actions to the HMActionSet in order to execute, or make the action set/scene do anything.

For e.g., I'd like to set desired thermostat temperate to 22 degree Celsius when I execute the Wake Up or Good Morning pre-defined scene under a HMHome.

In order to do so, you would create an HMAction (or more precisely, HMCharacteristicWriteAction - a subclass of HMAction), that writes the value 24 to the thermostat's desired temperature HMCharacteristic.

Once the HMAction is created (and you can create multiple such actions), add that HMAction to the predefined scene. Look at the iOS api for the exact api calls to do so.

In the HMCatalog app, take a look at the 'ActionSetCreator' class.

Also, you can see this action by adding HMActions in the HMCatalog itself. Drill down to a thermostat (or any other homekit paired service). Change the values of some HMCharacteristics under the HMService, then drill back up and save your scene (I may be off from the exact screen by screen details, as writing this out of memory on an airplane seat, but you get the point - hopefully).

Once you have (any) HMActions listed under a pre-defined scene - try saying the name of the scene to Siri (or you can simply execute it by pressing on the scene on HMCatalog).

If the thermostat (or other HomeKit service) is properly paired, you should see your state problem resolved.

Comment: hi @John Doe Can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584045/hmlocationevent-sample  and if possible can you please help me?