# HMLocationEvent Sample

Tags: ios9, homekit, ios-homekit

I am implementing HMLocatinEvent in my HMHome. I am trying the below code but one thing I didn't get is I don't know how to execute functionality like incase if I left home have to switch off all the lights. I didn't find any method related to the actionset. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Requirement: I want to switch off all the HMAccessories incase if I left home.

**Questions**:

1. To achieve the requirement Do I need to use HMLocationEvent and HMEventTrigger? or is there any alternate?
2. Incase if I has to use HMLocationEvent and HMEventTrigger how can I perform some action in the actions incase of enter/exit of the specified region?
3. Do I need to implement the CLLocationManager and delegate methods to use the HMLocationEvent?

   ```
   HMLocationEvent *locEvent = [[HMLocationEvent alloc] initWithRegion:region1];
   ```

   `region1.notifyOnEntry = YES;`

   ```
   region1.notifyOnExit = YES;

   CLRegion *region1 =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:[selectedLoc coordinate] radius:5 identifier:@"Office"];

   NSDateComponents *com = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   com.second = 1;

   HMEventTrigger *tr = [[HMEventTrigger alloc] initWithName:eventName.text events:[NSArray arrayWithObject:locEvent] predicate:[HMEventTrigger predicateForEvaluatingTriggerOccurringOnDateWithComponents:com]];
   [selectedHome addTrigger:tr completionHandler:^(NSError *err)
    {

    }];
   ```

Thank you for the valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

My concept is to use geofence 
1) Create geofence of ur home
2) just get the location of the house and create a fence with 50meters radius
3)Now create a code that listen for exist the geofence area and implement the corresponding code

reference for geo fence

http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

Comment: This is different from the HomeKit location Event